# Signs of a Neimark-Sacker bifurcation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

[image: neimark-sacker]

This bifurcation diagram looks to me like it could just be a lot of little pitchforks.

Is there something visual/graphical about it that gives it away as a Neimark-Sacker bifurcation?

Comment: Honestly, it looks more like cascade of period-doubling bifurcations. Of course you should include additional information about your diagram: at least you should say what mapping are you considering.

Comment: Agreeing 100% with @Evgeny on the last sentence, sometimes people plot the Neimark-Sacker projection on one of the space directions, and this may be the case (but you don't tell us...). For a period doubling it seems to me that one should expect clear lines in the beginning instead of so many points.